# Calculate River Runoff Volume (Q) with GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, hydrology

I want to calculate Hydropower between points at a River. I already created a Rivernetwork and the Accumulationmap (without weighting) with r.watershed.
My next Step was to set equivalent points along the River and find out their elevation -> done.
So now I want to calculate the Rivervolume for each point (along the River).
For this purpose I downloaded Precipitation data.

My Idea was to multiply the Accumulationmap with the Cell Size and the Precipitationmap (Previously, the card was processed that only the outflow remains on each cell (Runoff=Precipitation - Evapotranspiration)). But I´m not sure if that makes sense because the Accumulation says only how much Cells flow in but not which one (and there are Different Runoffs from different cells -> some also negative).

Do you have an idea how I can realize that and calculate the Riverrunoff for the points?

Comment: Calculating runoff from precipitation over a catchment basin is a complicated task. There are many additional factors beyond the drainage area and total precipitation: infiltration, slope, evaporation, manning coefficient, etc. You probably should be looking at models such as HEC-HMS.

Comment: I dont need to calculate the precipitation over a cathcment basin (calculation without basins) because i use a constant infiltration

Answer (score 1):

What about using r.watershed with the flow input parameter?

```
r.watershed elevation="elevation" flow="runoff" accumulation="flow_accumulation" ...
```

For the flow input you need to provide a raster map representing amount of overland flow per cell. For a simplified approach assuming no groundwater flow etc. you can use your generated runoff map (precipitation-evapotranspiration). The output accumulation map provides than an estimate of the accumulated flow from the entire upstream area for each cell.

Of course you can use other calculation steps before to correct for groundwater infiltration per cell if you have that information available. Moreover with that tool it is also not possible to calculate runtimes (i.e. how long it takes for a flood to move downstream etc.).

For more hydrologic analysis this page might help: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Hydrological_Sciences

Comment: I also thought about to do it like you said. What would you say If i do: Overlandflow=Precipitation-evapotranspiration-Infiltration (Infiltrtaion constant in the whole Region) and use that as Flow input for r.Watershed with the -a Flag?. With that Acc_map i can calculate the Streams.
Then multiply the new Acc_map by Cellsize to get Liters/time (it should be Q the right?). And then set points along the Stream and find out the Accumulation*Cellsize value(here it should be Volume Q in Lite/time) and the elevation. Does that sound reasonable?